# Can you see previous values for an atom in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

"Clojure metaphysics construes identity as something we humans impose on a succession of unchanging values produced by a process over time".

[image: Imposed identity on a sequence of states]

[(Higginsworth, October 2015)](https://www.braveclojure.com/zombie-metaphysics/)

If this is true, if identity surronds all these states, then I should be able to do something like this.

```
user=> (def wow (atom 1))
#'user/wow
user=> (swap! wow (fn [cur] "You say 'Hello'."))
"You say 'Hello'."
user=> (swap! wow (fn [cur] "I say 'Goodbye'."))
"I say 'Goodbye'."
user=> (swap! wow (fn [cur] "Hello, hello!"))
"Hello, hello!"

; Can I do this?
user=> (get-old-atom-state wow 0)
1
(get-old-atom-state wow 1)
"You say 'Hello'"
```

Is this so? Or does Clojure actually GC the old values if not used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If this is true, if identity surronds all these states, then I should be able to do something like this.

I don't really see any justification for this "should", philosophically. "Aaron Bell" is an identity that encompasses many states you have been in in the past, but I can't interact with, or even observe, any of those past states. The only way I would know about any of them is if somebody had observed them and written down those observations in some immutable object that I can refer to.

Clojure's identities behave the same way: you can take a snapshot at any time, and after you do, you can look at that snapshot whenever you want. But states nobody looked at are lost forever.

Comment: "I thought, therefore I was" - the identity formerly known as René Descartes

Answer (score 2):

The JVM does garbage collect the old and not referenced values of an atom.

However, you can [set up a listener](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/add-watch) to the changes of the atom values and store the old values manually to another atom.

```
user=> (def wow (atom 1))
#'user/wow

user=> (def wow-history (atom ()))
#'user/wow-history

user=> (add-watch wow :hist
          (fn [_ _ old _] (swap! wow-history conj old)))
```

Mutate the atom:

```
user=> (swap! wow (fn [cur] "You say 'Hello'."))
"You say 'Hello'."

user=> (swap! wow (fn [cur] "I say 'Goodbye'."))
"I say 'Goodbye'."

user=> (swap! wow (fn [cur] "Hello, hello!"))
"Hello, hello!"
```

Now lets check the values in the history:

```
user=> @wow-history
("I say 'Goodbye'." "You say 'Hello'." 1)
```

Do not forget to clean up the `wow-history` atom when you do not need the old values to prevent memory leaks.

```
user=> (reset! wow-history ())
()
```